# Pygame ship movement only Up & Down (left right is working)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

## This part is gamefunction.py file

```
import sys

import pygame

def check_keydown_events(event,ship):
    """Respond to the keypressess."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ship.moving_up = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        ship.moving_down = True 


def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """Respond to the keyreleases."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ship.moving_up = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        ship.moving_down = False

def check_events(ship):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event,ship)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)
```

## this is named ship.py

```
import pygame

class Ship():

    def __init__(self,ai_settings,screen):
        """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        #Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        #Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
        
        #Store a decimal value for the ship's center.
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx) 
        #Movement Flags
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False


    def update(self):
        """Update the ship's position based on the movement flag."""
        #Update the ship's center value, not the rect
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right<self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left>0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor 
        #Up-dwon motion added ***Please check the logic for 1200x800 screen*** 
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.top<self.screen_rect.top:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom>800:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        #Update rect object from self.center.
        self.rect.centerx = self.center
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you having an error? Are the code not doing as you expect? You need to define the question in the body and explain what's wrong, what you want it to do and also provide a [mcve]. Make sure your code is properly formated as well so it's easier to read the code.

Comment: code not doing as expected on up and down movement

Comment: When you ask a question you have to make sure to format it properly so it's readable (I've done it for you now though). You also have to explain what the code is doing (what's happening) and explain what you were trying to do. Since you haven't provided a [mcve] we cannot test the code to find the problem. When you write _"code not doing as expected"_ we can only guess what the problem is. If you instead write _"the ship is moving in the opposite direction than what I want it to move"_ we'll know what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

Source: [Python Crash Course](https://www.nostarch.com/pythoncrashcourse)

Just a few tweeks in `ship.py`:

Under `self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)`, add `self.bottom = float(self.rect.bottom)` and change:

```
if self.moving_up and self.rect.top<self.screen_rect.top:
    self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom>800:
    self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
```

to:

```
if self.moving_up and self.rect.top<self.screen_rect.top:
    self.bottom -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom<800:
    self.bottom += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
```

and finally under `self.rect.centerx = self.center`, add `self.rect.bottom = self.bottom`.

This should make you be able to go up and down in your game!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a problem I spotted, in these functions:

```
check_keydown_events
check_keyup_events
check_events
```

In each of these cases, you are doing `if-elif-elif-elif` statements. This means when the `if` statement is `True`, the `elif` statements will not run.

In your case, if the left or right keys are pressed, you will never be able to move up or down.

You should change this code so that you only use `if-elif` with the up/down and left/right movement separately.

Here is one (corrected) example:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
    ship.moving_right = True
elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
    ship.moving_left = True
if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
    ship.moving_up = True
elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
    ship.moving_down = True
```

Your problem will be fixed if you change each `if-elif-elif-elif` statement to `if-elif-if-elif`.

Answer (score 0):

**Ship.py**

```
.....
self.bottom = float(self.rect.bottom)
self.moving_up = False
self.moving_down = False

def update(self):
    .....
    # check if the ship is moving up and stop the ship to move up if 
    # it's top edge position is less than 
    # screen's top (top right corner is 0,0) position
    if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > self.screen_rect.top:
        self.bottom -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

    # check if the ship is moving down and stop the ship when it's
    # bottom position is greater than the screen bottom edge position.
    if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
        self.bottom += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

    self.rect.bottom = self.bottom
```

**game_function.py**

```
def check_keydown_event(event, ship):
    """Respond to keypresses"""
    ....
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ship.moving_up = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        ship.moving_down = True


def check_keyup_event(event, ship):
    ....
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ship.moving_up = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        ship.moving_down = False
```